# The H1 tag wont load on my page only the javascript part, why is that?

Tags: javascript, html

When I load this page to the browser the Javascript shows up but the HTML (H1 tag) doesn't. I haven't been able to figure out why I cant get HTML to show up on the page. Im new to both Javascript and HTML...clearly.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="data_generator.js"></script>
 </head> 
   <body>
   <h1>hello</h1>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.html('');

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
      $tweet.appendTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$body.html('');` wipes out everything rendered inside the `<body>` tag giving you a blank page

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the `<h1>` tag when you clear the inner HTML of the `body` tag by calling `$('body').html('')`. Why don't you work in a different container element that you can clear:

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $root = $('#root');
    // $root.html(''); // Already empty. Don't need to clear it.

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
      $tweet.appendTo($root);
      index -= 1;
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl said, `$body.html('');` clears all previous html content of the body tag. More simply it just replaces the contents with what is inside the quotes, or in this case nothing.

Here is documentation on the subject:

[JQuery html() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

**EDIT:**
Inspired by Sean's answer,
If you want to use the body container directly you can do so like this:

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    // $body.html(''); // This clears it and since you don't want to, you shouldn't run this command.

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
      $tweet.appendTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: So why would that line of code be added in? (I was started with this code, I didn't write it) Should I just take it out?

Comment: @Ashleigh yea they include that to clear the previous code. It is a good habit to include lines like that to isolate and make sure it is in a separate environment. You should try taking it out, since you know what's on there and it shouldn't affect previous posts.